# Chrome Scrollbar Bounces from bottom

Tags: css, google-chrome, scrollbar

So while working on a project I noticed that when I scrolled to the bottom the scrollbar would *bounce* back up a page.

Originally I had to make the front page have less vertical space for the `footer` and add the space for every other page.

So I moved:
    body {margin-bottom: 150px;}

To:

```
body:not(.home) {margin-bottom: 150px;}
```

I'm answering my own question here though it's very clear Chrome has widespread issues with the scrollbar behavior in general. For people who *aren't* web designers it *is* possible to override the behavior on a live website and in some cases (with extreme subjectivity) programs (e.g. maybe the bookmarks page) though the issue in browser pages is overriding the browser's internal CSS which isn't always possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix, at least in the scenario I faced, was to *split* the `margin` in two and give the other *half* of the spacing to the `padding-bottom`.

So in example, this:

```
body {margin-bottom: 100px;}
```

Would become this:

```
body
{
 margin-bottom: 50px;
 padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

This is however generally *not* an acceptable solution as there are very explicit reasons why `margin` and `padding` are two *different contexts* however the project I'm working on is *very* graphically heavy and requires breaking proper CSS conventions.

---

For **non-web developers/designers** who may come across this issue and page, as I mentioned in the question above, it is possible to override a website's CSS code if the **CSS selector** can be specific enough to only effect one website. The code would then have to be applied to the browser's master style sheet. I've done this in the past to negate Google *forcing* ads even around my Adblock Plus filter subscription and *won*. Each browser has it's own way of applying *default styling*, since this is a **Chrome** specific issue and I'm not as familiar with Chrome I did some digging to provide some bread crumbs and hopefully make someone's life just a bit easier:

https://superuser.com/questions/52967/change-default-css-of-google-chrome